# Tableau Google Ads Connector

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I am reaching out to you with a question regarding connecting Google Ads source with Tableau Desktop. I saved the source and set it as an auto-refreshing extract, from a certain point I can no longer add new reports due to too many connections to the source. The content of the error below. Has anyone of you had this problem and managed to resolve it?

Error message: Unknown Failure (status code = 5054, Tableau encountered an error while communicating with Google Ads: RateExceededError.RATE_EXCEEDED. Your Ads rate limit was exceeded due to too much access in a short period of time or too much access within the last day. Try again later.

Comment: Are you on a free Google Ads license?  The error means that you're doing too much based on the limitations of your license (so, nothing to do with Tableau).  There's no "solution" other than to a) do less or b) pay to be allowed to do more.

Small caveat maybe -- refreshing that extract isnt a ton by itself, but if you're refreshing many of them (or even a single one, but very often) then each of those extracts counts towards the same total in Google.  I don't think Google differentiates between refreshes or random querying either, so if you have a "Live" one, that could be hogging it all

Comment: @oooyaya I use a regular account to which I have full permissions, Tableau Desktop provides the ability to link this source. Good point about the amount of data - I included all the metrics available in the account